# Why am I getting this error message when trying to add a COM reference to "Windows Script Host Object Model"?

Tags: c#, com, visual-studio-2019

I have a 32 bit C# application in which I am trying to add a reference to the "IWshRuntimeLibrary" library, which is a .NET wrapper for a COM component. When I try to add a reference to it, it fails and shows a yellow warning icon next to the reference. If I try to compile regardless of the warning icon, I receive the following message:

> Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "IWshRuntimeLibrary". Verify that (1) the COM component is registered correctly and (2) your target platform is the same as the bitness of the COM component. For example, if the COM component is 32-bit, your target platform must not be 64-bit.

I have tried removing the reference and then re-adding it, but the error message still shows up. I have also verified that wshom.ocx exists in both %SYSTEMROOT%\System32 and %SYSTEMROOT%\syswow64. I've also made sure to run Visual Studio as an administrator, just in case it's related to permissions.

Can anybody tell me how to get rid of this error?

Comment: I can't reproduce. I can successfully register it and run `new IWshRuntimeLibrary.FileSystemObject()` in 32 or 64b. It's probably a problem with your machine setup. You can try to call regsvr32 wshom.ocx

Comment: SimonMourier, do I call that from the command line? What does that command do?

Comment: Well, it works once the reference is added obviously. What you can do is try this w/o any reference: `var type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);` if type is null then you have a installation issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out what the issue was. The problem seems to have stemmed from the fact that we delay sign our project. If we run the command to register the assembly for verification skipping, the compiler error went away.

```
sn.exe -Vr *,[YOUR_PUBLICKEYTOKEN_HERE]
```